# ¿Cómo buscar un elemento específico en una matriz ingresada por el usuario?

Tags: c, matrices

El usuario debe ingresar una pregunta con comodines, por ejemplo: suma {a} + {b}. Debo hacer que separe los comodines que son a y b. Lo tenía hecho en un vector pero al cambiarlo a matriz no logro solucionarlo. No llevo mucho usando c y aún estoy aprendiendo:( gracias!. `textoPregunta` esta definida como:
`char textoPregunta[numPreguntas][100]`, siendo `numPreguntas` la cantidad de preguntas que el usuario ingrese.

```
                printf("\nIngresa el texto de la pregunta: ");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s ", &textoPregunta[i]);
                //printf("%s\n", textoPregunta);
                for(k=0; k<100; k++){
                    printf("%s", textoPregunta[k]);
                    if(textoPregunta[k] == 0){ 
                        break;
                    }
                    if(textoPregunta[k][j] == '{'){
                        k++;
                        for(k; textoPregunta[k][j] != '}'; k++){
                            comodin[a][b] = textoPregunta[k][j];
                            a++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                printf("\nLos comodines son: %s", comodin);
```

Muchas gracias..!

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Al ejecutar así no me sale nada, se cierra la ejecución

Comment: Muestre todo su programa, sin editar.